# Case sensitive recognition in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following file: http://pastebin.ca/2495415

The problem is that case sensitive of the variable `$username` is not recognized. For example if i have the user `Lord` and in the database is registered as `lord` it won't recognize the username.
In mysql i have tried selecting the username `Lord` with `SELECT username, car, damage, location FROM garage WHERE username = 'Lord'` and it worked so I guess that mysql is not the problem but PHP.
In PHP there is the following line

```
$carshit = mysql_query("SELECT username, car, damage, location FROM garage 
           WHERE id=".quote_smart($cartouse)."");
```

Which i am very confident that I detected correctly :)

I have tried doing:

```
$carshit = mysql_query("SELECT username, car, damage, location FROM garage 
WHERE id=".quote_smart($cartouse)." AND username='$username'");
```

AND

```
$carshit = mysql_query("SELECT username, car, damage, location FROM garage 
WHERE id=".quote_smart($cartouse)." AND username LIKE '$username'");
```

AND

```
$carshit = mysql_query("SELECT username, car, damage, location FROM garage 
WHERE username COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%$username%'
id=".quote_smart($cartouse)."");
```

This one returns  mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource. Which i think it means that the `mysql_query` is not valid, may not recognize COLLATION..

Tried also

```
$carshit = mysql_query("SELECT username, car, damage, location FROM garage 
           WHERE lower(username) = lower($username)") 
           AND id=".quote_smart($cartouse)."");
```

This is the highlighted code that i have focused

```
if($oooocstatuss!=Ready){
  $driverpanel=show;
  if($_POST['usecar']){
    $cartouse=strip_tags($_POST['cars']);
      if($cartouse==''){
        echo "<div class=\"hightct\">Error!</div>";
      }else{
        $carshit = mysql_query("SELECT username, car, damage, location 
                   FROM garage WHERE AND id=".quote_smart($cartouse)."");
        while ($carrinfo = mysql_fetch_row($carshit)) {
          $carowner = $carrinfo[0];
          $carrtype = $carrinfo[1];
          $carrdam = $carrinfo[2];
          $carrlocate = $carrinfo[3];
        }
        if($carowner!=$username){
          echo "<div id='theBox' class='failureBox'>This Is not your car!</div>";
        }else{ //does operations that should do.
```

HTML is smth like this:

```
<form name="form6" method="get" action="main.php?page=oc....."> 
  <input name="id" value="170" type="hidden">
  <input name="username" value="Lord" type="hidden">
  <input name="page" value="oc" type="hidden">
  <input name="leave" value="driver" type="hidden">
  <input name="disoc" id="disoc" value="Leave OC" class="sub" type="submit">
</form>
<form id="form6" action="" method="post" name="form6">
            <td width="50%">
                <div align="center">
                    <select id="cars" name="cars">
                        <option value="3815">
                            Bugatti Veyron, 0% Damage
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
```

You select the following field and `if($carowner!=$username){` then it echo's message
`This is not your car` And everything because of the case sensitive problem.

Please help i ran out of ideas.

Comment: Unless you've specifically configured it as such, mysql defaults to case-insentive matches anyways. Plus, `where collate ...` is not valid. You need to use [CONVERT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html). If you had bare minimum error handling... `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error())` you'd have been informed of this.

Comment: @Marc B So in my case to use CONVERT would be smth like: `SELECT CONVERT `... but why would i need to convert. CONVERT provides a way to convert data between different character sets. This has the same char set just that smaller and bigger letters.

Comment: yes, but even with the same charset there's CI and CS versions - (c)ase (I)nsensitive v.s. (c)ase (s)ensitive. if you defined your tables with a CS version, then you'll have to convert to the CI equivalent, or do things like `lower(field1) = lower(field2)`

Comment: @MarcB ok i managed to figure out smth: There are 2 tables that have column username and in the condition `if($carowner!=$username)` it asks in English something like if (lord different than Lord) than echo's mesage. So i need to know if there is any function that can do something like `$carowner = function_that makes_this_variable case_insestive($carrinfo[0]);` is there any function that does this not in SQL but in PHP?

Comment: manage to figure it out i did it with `strtolower`. Working now, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem i managed to overcome it like this:

```
  $carowner = strtolower($carrinfo[0]);
  $usernm = strtolower($username);
  $carrtype = $carrinfo[1];
  $carrdam = $carrinfo[2];
  $carrlocate = $carrinfo[3];
}
if($carowner!=$usernm){
  echo "<div id='theBox' class='failureBox'>This Is not your car!</div>";
```